# NullPointerException while using intent to pass string array

Tags: android

I want to recieve my array values from players.java to player_name.java.
It gives NumberFormatException when I click on the button on player_name.java.

I have used two intents in these two activities. If I remove one intent which passes an array then it is working, otherwise it is not working

How do I use multiple intents in single activity? Please help.

player.java

```
public class players extends Activity {

    LinearLayout player_layout;
    Bundle b;

    List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.players);

        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String resStr = b.getString("name");

        player_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_layout);

        EditText[] ed1 = new EditText[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];
        Button add_player = new Button(players.this);
        add_player.setText("Add Players");

        for(int i=1; i <= Integer.parseInt(resStr); i++)
        {
            ed1[i] = new EditText(players.this);
            allEds.add(ed1[i]);
            player_layout.addView(ed1[i]);
            ed1[i].setId(i);
            ed1[i].setHint("enter player" +i+ "name");
            ed1[i].setHeight(50);
            ed1[i].setWidth(300);
        }

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        player_layout.addView(add_player, lp);

        add_player.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(players.this, player_name.class);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(players.this, player_name.class);
                String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

                for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                    strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                    // intent.putExtra("playerName",b.getString("name"));
                    intent.putExtra("playerName",strings);
                }
                intent1.putExtra("play", b.getString("name"));
                startActivity(intent);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

player_name.java

```
public class player_name extends Activity {

    LinearLayout player_name;
    Bundle b,b1;

    List<TextView> allEds = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    List<Button> allplus = new ArrayList<Button>();
    List<Button> allminus = new ArrayList<Button>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_name);

        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String resStr = b.getString("name");
        b1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] result = b1.getStringArray("playerName");

        player_name = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_name);

        TextView[] ed1 = new TextView[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];
        Button[] plus = new Button[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];
        Button[] minus = new Button[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];

        for(int i=1;i<=Integer.parseInt(resStr);i++)
        {
            ed1[i] = new TextView(player_name.this);
            plus[i] = new Button(player_name.this);
            minus[i] = new Button(player_name.this);

            allEds.add(ed1[i]);
            allplus.add(plus[i]);
            allminus.add(minus[i]);

            player_name.addView(ed1[i]);
            player_name.addView(plus[i]);
            player_name.addView(minus[i]);

            ed1[i].setId(i);
            ed1[i].setHeight(50);
            ed1[i].setWidth(300);
            ed1[i].setText(result[i]);
            ed1[i].setTextColor(Color.CYAN);

            plus[i].setId(i);
            plus[i].setHeight(50);
            plus[i].setWidth(300);
            plus[i].setText("+");
            plus[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            minus[i].setId(i);
            minus[i].setHeight(50);
            minus[i].setWidth(300);
            minus[i].setText("-");
            minus[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
```

logcat :-

```
06-18 04:03:25.657: D/dalvikvm(300): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 767 objects / 55840 bytes in 87ms
06-18 04:03:29.057: E/global(300): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
06-18 04:03:29.057: E/global(300): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
06-18 04:03:29.057: E/global(300):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
06-18 04:03:29.057: E/global(300):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
06-18 04:03:29.057: E/global(300):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
06-18 04:03:29.057: E/global(300):  at com.example.snooder.splash$1.run(splash.java:35)
06-18 04:03:55.678: D/AndroidRuntime(300): Shutting down VM
06-18 04:03:55.678: W/dalvikvm(300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snooder/com.example.snooder.player_name}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:406)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at com.example.snooder.player_name.onCreate(player_name.java:41)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-18 04:03:55.717: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you show us the logcat from the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Well the mistake was that you were using `b1` which you hadn't initalize
**Your code**

```
b = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] result = b1.getStringArray("playerName");
```

**It should be**

```
 b1 = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] result = b1.getStringArray("playerName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class name

```
public class player_name extends Activity {
```

And you property name:

```
LinearLayout player_name;
```

Are the same. This may cause the null-pointer exception. 
More over **according to [Java name convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) you should declare classes with capital later and without underscore**, like this: `PlayerName`

Comment: my all the classes and layouts names are like this only to identify which class is accosiated to which layout. and they all work well .

Comment: They probably do, but just as a style convention, it's best to name classes in "MixedCase" form. Consistency makes your code more readable, which makes it easier to debug and easier for other people to read it and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
check your intent key you can pass 

intent.putExtra("playerName",strings); 

and 

intent1.putExtra("play",b.getString("name"));


and you can get intent


    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String resStr = b.getString("name");
    b1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] result = b1.getStringArray("playerName");

used only string in result variable
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is here:

```
            String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

            for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                // intent.putExtra("playerName",b.getString("name"));
                intent.putExtra("playerName",strings);
            }
```

So *strings* is an array of string references, initially all set to null. Then in your loop, you set the first element of the array to a string, then write the **whole** array to the intent "playerName". Then you set the second element of the array to a string, and write the whole array all over again. I'm betting that **intent.putExtra()** doesn't like an array with null elements in it.

You should have done:

```
            String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

            for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                // intent.putExtra("playerName",b.getString("name"));
            }
            intent.putExtra("playerNames",strings);
```

However, the logcat doesn't indicate this is the problem, so we'll move on.

The logcat output indicates that you tried to call **parseInt()** with a null value in **player_name.onCreate()**.

The relevant code seems to be:

```
    String resStr = b.getString("name");
    EditText[] ed1 = new EditText[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];
```

Clearly, *resStr* is a null value. If the string property "name" was not set in the intent, then *resStr* would be null and you'd get the effect you're seeing.

Further, best practices require that you wrap a try..catch block around your call to *parseInt()* just in case it's passed any string that can't be parsed into an integer.

As an aside, "name" is a very poor choice for the name of a property that contains an integer value. Are you sure you didn't intend some other name?

As another aside, you're calling `Integer.parseInt(resStr)` over and over again in your code. This is inefficient; you should instead do something like this:

```
    len = Integer.parseInt(resStr);
    TextView[] ed1 = new TextView[len+1];
    Button[] plus = new Button[len+1];
    Button[] minus = new Button[len+1];
    etc....
```

In fact, why are you passing an integer value as a string in the first place? You can (and should) pass integer values in an intent. Your code should look like:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int len = intent.getIntExtra("name", 1);
```